# Xmlstarlet fails to preserve original formatting (windows)

Tags: xmlstarlet

I have an xml document that I'm using xmlstarlet to edit, removing the surrounding C tags if a descendant tag contains a matching text.

Sample xml file:

```
<a>
    <b>
         <c><d>RED</d></c>
         <c><d>BLUE</d></c>
    </b>
</a>
```

Using the xpath syntax:

```
//d[text()='RED']/ancestor::c[1]
```

I am able to delete the nearest c tag which has a d tag with text 'RED' with the xmlstarlet arguments:

```
xml ed -P -O --inplace --delete //d[text()='RED']/ancestor::c[1]
```

The problem is that the original formatting is not preserved, as the 'P' switch is supposed to ensure, with the output file missing newlines and looking something like:

```
<a>        <b>                       <c><d>BLUE</d></c>        </b></a>
```

Note that I've been using notepad to check the formatting before and after the edit. Any suggestions for how to get xmlstarlet to preserve the original formatting would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `xml --version` say? I tried this with 1.4.2 and 1.5.0; the newlines were not removed.

Comment: 1.5.0
compiled against libxml2 2.9.1, linked with 20901
compiled against libxslt 1.1.28, linked with 10128

Strange. This was on Windows that you tried? Could it be some kind of encoding issue, lf vs cr+lf, this sort of thing?

Comment: oh, I see, the newlines are getting changed to lf. I wasn't using notepad so I didn't notice.